# PHP & MySQL: Truncate multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, truncate

I tried to truncate a table but why is it not working? must something wrong in the database query?

```
$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name`";

$result = $connection -> query($sql);
```

Ideally, I want to truncate all tables in one go - is it possible?

if you wonder what is inside the class that I use to make the database queries, here is it,

```
#connects the database and handling the result
class __database {

 protected $connection = null;
 protected $error = null;

 #make a connection
 public function __construct($hostname,$username,$password,$database)
 {
  $this -> connection = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
  {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  }
 }

 ...

 #performs a query on the database
 public function query($query)
 {
  $result = $this -> connection -> query($query); 
  if($result) 
  {
   return $result;
  } 
  else
  {
   $this -> error = $this -> connection -> error;
   return false;
  }

 }


 #display error
 public function get_error() 
 {
  return $this -> error;
 }

 #closes the database connection when object is destroyed.
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this -> connection -> close();
    }
}
```

thanks.

**edit:**

below is how I call the db object,

```
# the host used to access DB
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

# the username used to access DB
define('DB_USER', 'root');

# the password for the username
define('DB_PASS', 'xxx');

# the name of your databse 
define('DB_NAME', 'xxx'); 

$connection = new __database(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

Comment: nothing/ no error has been shown at all! I don't know why the db class I made cannot show the error when there must be a error somewhere!

Comment: Have you tried calling the get_error() method? Can you provide a bit more of the code from where you create your db object / call it?

Comment: @jasonbar: I provided the code above in my edit. the trouble is I never cal the get_error() method as I don't know how to call it! made that db class from a tutorial elsewhere and now I have forgotten everything!

Comment: double check that the mysql user has sufficient privileges.  see the mysql error log. make sure you are not mixing up development and live databases (truncating in one, verifying in another).

Comment: found the error. I ran the wrong file! arggggg - stupid ME!!! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the help guys! here is my answer,

```
# truncate data from all table
# $sql = "SHOW TABLES IN 1hundred_2011";
# or,
$sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '".DB_NAME."'";

# use the instantiated db connection object from the init.php, to process the query
$tables = $connection -> fetch_all($sql);
//print_r($tables);

foreach($tables as $table) 
{
    //echo $table['TABLE_NAME'].'<br/>';

    # truncate data from this table
    # $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `developer_configurations_cms`";

    # use the instantiated db connection object from the init.php, to process the query
    # $result = $connection -> query($sql);

    # truncate data from this table
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `".$table['TABLE_NAME']."`";

    # use the instantiated db connection object from the init.php, to process the query
    $result = $connection -> query($sql);
}
```

Comment: I had to execute the first sql first before getting the results. I got something like this: https://gist.github.com/Stephen304/f09fe7d0e08abbb2d820

Comment: As in that "$connection -> fetch_all($sql);" thing didn't work great for me.

Answer (score 1):

By the MySQL Reference Manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

You can only delete one table at a time using TRUNCATE.

You could try executing multiple queries in one PHP query by using a ";" delimiter between them.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple different option.

- Run a query for each truncate
- Create a stored procedure that will truncate all the tables you want to do.

Comment: I can't even truncate a table for some reasons. must the the error in the database query?