# What is the SQL command that 'resets' the database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a SQL command that 'resets' the database in MySQL?

By reset I mean, all rows are deleted and auto increment are reset.

Comment: Did you mean just a single table or a database with a bunch of tables?

Comment: A database that has many tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `TRUNCATE`, as in `TRUNCATE TABLE mystuff`

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: How do I select all the tables that I want to TRUNCATE? TRUNCATE TABLE table1, table2 gives me an error.

Comment: The best way to do that is to run multiple queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702708/php-mysql-truncate-multiple-tables

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump -uuser -hhost -p --no-data name_of_database > backup_file_name.sql`

The above command will keep the entire structure of your database but without the data.  (that's what the `--no-data` param does).

Now when you want to **reset** your database you just:

`mysql -uuser -hhost -p < backup_file_name.sql`

View the .sql file created to see what its doing.  There are a bunch of options you can add to the `mysqldump` command.

Enjoy.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and unsafe.  Incorrect because `mysqldump` *preserves AUTO_INCREMENT offsets*, which is not what the OP wants.  Unsafe because your reset (`mysql ... < backup_file_name.sql`) will be applied to *whatever the user's default schema is*, not necessarily the schema you initially dumped.  Add a `-B` argument to `mysqldump` to make this safer.