# Unable to truncate multiple table at a time

Tags: mysql, truncate

I am trying to truncate 3 tables using their table names out of 5 tables. 
Is there any syntax for it as am unable to find

Can anyone give me reference?

Comment: truncate table users

Comment: Am asking not about one table

Comment: Please update the post explaining why you can't call truncate 3 times.

Comment: Is there an error message? Can you provide the code you are using? And can you let us know the table names causing an issue? We need more info :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & MySQL: Truncate multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702708/php-mysql-truncate-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to truncate multiple table

```
SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME in ('table1','table2','table3')
```

or 
run it **one by one**

```
truncate table table1
```